# How to display the edges of a mesh while in Object mode?

Tags: 3d-view, draw-mode

I sometimes like to view my models in wireframe mode, but it doesn't show individual faces, only lines representing the general formation of the object. With subdivisions (especially) this does not achieve what I'd really like to see, which is more of a "blueprint" look.

### Solid view:

[image]

### Wireframe:

[image]

### What I want (except this is solid):

[image]

#### What I want (except, this is edit mode, not an actual drawmode):

[image]

Is there a draw mode that can achieve this?

**P.S.:** *I don't mind if the answer uses Python. I'm not a Python programmer but I'd be able to understand the code (I've got programming experience and have used Python on and off before).*

Comment: Do you mean an outline that draws each edge, not just the general form?

Comment: @zeffii good idea. I'll do that.

Comment: @CharlesL yes that's what I mean.

Comment: There's probably a better answer, but you can add a "Wireframe" modifier to your model.

Comment: Yup, there IS a better answer: Properties/ Object/ Display: Switch "Maximum Draw Type" to "Wire".

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If I understand your question right, then you just need to enable **Draw All Edges** and **Wire** under the **Object properties**.

[image: All Edges Wire Display]

**Wire** draws all edges in the mesh that are not coplanar (edges not lying on the same mathematical plane). **Draw All Edges** draws these coplanar edges in wire display and wireframe mode.

Comment: Thanks this is what I meant. I somehow never noticed that option, even though I noticed the "Wire" option. (Amazing what you can miss lol).

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain too why there are two options and what they do.

Comment: For other people - like me - Object properties != view properties. It's in the rightmost panel under the "cube" button.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the solutions worked for anyone still ( in the newer versions ), I was able to turn on the edges in object mode in the following properties section :

```
Properties region -> Object Properties -> Viewport Display -> Show : Wireframe
```

Which gives the following look in the Object Mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you work with many objects you can select all objects and then press "alt" when you check the "wire" button. Then, all objects are solid + wire. Or install the very usefull addon Amaranth: http://pablovazquez.org/amaranth/