# Displaying the wireframe of a beveled Bezier curve

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe, draw-mode

I'm following a tutorial in which a Bezier curve is supposed to represent a vine. The vine is a collection of control points with their bevel depth and bevel resolution set appropriately:

[image]

However, the vine in the tutorial's included .blend file displays its wireframe over the typical solid viewport shading:

[image]

In both .blend files, Object Mode is selected. How do I get my .blend file to display a wireframed Bezier curve?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-to-display-the-edges-of-a-mesh-while-in-object-mode), I realized that you need to check the "Wire" checkbox within the Object Properties panel.

[image]