# How to get my [solid mode] object OUTLINES back?

Tags: objects, 3d-view

[image: Black Outlines][image: NO Black Outlines] I don't know how this happened, but suddenly, my OGL object outlines (in object mode) are now gone. This makes it difficult to see object edges when they are placed adjacent to other objects. I need the object mode outlines back, but HOW?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-to-display-the-edges-of-a-mesh-while-in-object-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple places you can enable outlines. The first is within the viewport, to highlight selected and active objects. You can find that option here: 
[image: Outline Selected]

The other is in the object properties, here:
[image: Display wire]

Enable wire to see the black edge outlines regardless of selection. Enable "Draw All Edges" to display all edges, whether coplanar or not. By default, coplanar edges are not drawn.

Comment: Thank you! The second one works fine, but only one object at a time. Is there a way to change ALL objects at the same time?

Comment: Select all objects, then hold ALT while pressing that checkbox. It will change all selected objects to match the active object.

Comment: @italic
Thanks for the useful tip,
one year later, in blender 2.76, select all object and hold CTRL+ALT to match active objet