# edges missing in wireframe view, but visible in edit mode

Tags: modeling

Sorry, I'm still a newbie to blender,
but why are some edges visible only in edit mode, but not in wireframe view? is it a bug or am I missing something here?

edit mode: Edges visible.
Object mode, wireframe view: Pooff, they're gone. what can i do to fix this? / thanks
[image]
[image]

Comment: Also related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-to-display-the-edges-of-a-mesh-while-in-object-mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a feature from the past to save performance. Object Mode does not draw all edges by default, but skips them here and there. You have to tell Blender to draw all edges.

Go to Object tab, and tick Draw all Edges in the Display panel

[image].