# Why my object looks like this in Object Mode?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

When I am in edit mode it looks like this:

[image]

When I am in object mode it looks like this:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: check geometry: doubles, normals

Comment: Possible duplicate of [edges missing in wireframe view, but visible in edit mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58580/edges-missing-in-wireframe-view-but-visible-in-edit-mode)

Comment: Duplicate of a duplicate, please use search before asking

Comment: Does object have any modifiers? Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload your file and include link here to avoid further guessing

Answer (score 2):

**First possibility.**

Change **Viewport Shading** to **Solid** or press <kbd>Z</kbd> in **Object Mode**.

[image: viewport]

**Second possibility.**

Change **Maximum Draw Type** in **Object** tab to at least **Solid**. Have object selected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to change Viewport Shading to Solid or press Z in Object Mode.

Comment: The viewport shading in your first screenshot was set to Solid already. According to your answer it wasn't set to Solid in your second screenshot. Was that made intentionally?