# Missing edges in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, edges, extrude

[image]

Why there is no edge inside red circle and why the edges seems to be raised inside blue circle though i didn't extrude those edges? And i didn't use any modifier. It's just in edit mode.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58580/edges-missing-in-wireframe-view-but-visible-in-edit-mode/58581#58581

Comment: in the above link, the problem is its missing in wireframe mode but visible in edit mode. But for me, it's missing in both of the modes.

Comment: Check again, that have not accidentally extruded inwards, since the shown blue edge clearly looks like you did. Also it seems, you have accidentally deleted (probably dissolved) the missing endge. Just delete the face, fill in the edge and the two faces to fix it.
If that is not the case, how about submitting your blend file, that makes working out issues way easier. If your not shure how to, try [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: If the draw all edges option doesn't help, you may have multiple faces at that location. In edit mode with face select mode you see a small square at the centre of each face, are there extras at that location? You could also have an n-gon there, does that area always select as one face?