# How to paint the edges of a mesh/outline its topology AND have it show after rendering?

Tags: edit-mode, edges, wireframe

Is there anyway to paint the edges of a mesh? I'd like to be able to see the outlined edges and vertices of a mesh outside of edit mode.
This [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-to-display-the-edges-of-a-mesh-while-in-object-mode) is verbatim what I'm asking, but the wireframe doesn't show after I render the image.
I have attempted to fill in the lines and edges using grease pencil, but I'd like a more robust solution.
[image]
^ visible in object mode
[image]
^ unseen after rendering

Comment: If you have what you want to see from the question you've linked, you can use "viewport render" operation to render exactly what you see in the 3D viewport.